# Need to find list of exact FileNames based on an input file number

Tags: c#

I need to make a list of image files based on a file number that I input. I can only find image files that have exactly that file number, even though the image file may have the same characters before and/or after.
So, I am trying to locate some image files in a folder structure based on a file number.
So if the file number is '00441' I need to find files numbered like this:

- IM00441_000A.jpg
- IM00441_205A.jpg
- IM00441_110D.jpg
- IM00441_A11.jpg

So, this wouldn’t be a problem if every image file had a underscore like these examples, BUT, there are some that do not have an underscore.
AND there are file numbers that have a suffix like we have '00441' AND '00441A'
So, in addition to the image files listed above, I might have:

- IM00441A_000A.JPG
- IM00441A_105A.JPG
- IM00441A_110A.JPG
- IM00441A_302A.JPG

So, because of these problems, I cannot break at the underscore and I can't use StartsWith (like the code below), because all of these example all start with '00441', just some end with 'A'.
This is the code that I have so far, but it doesn’t work because of what I said previously.

```
    LocalFile = "IM" + FileNumber;
    if (ValidateFilepath(di))
        lstDocuments = di.GetFiles("*.jpg")
        .Where(file => file.Name.ToUpperInvariant().StartsWith(LocalFile))
        .Select(file => file.FullName).ToList(); //  The ToUpperInvariant() makes the file name upper case, because the actual file names are not consistent.
```

Comment: So you want all files whose names contain 00441 AND the characters before and after are non-numeric?

Comment: why not pass the pattern you are looking for into the di.GetFiles() call? `di.GetFiles($"*{FileNumber}*.jpg");` For example of course, you would use string interpolation to build that pattern, but you should get the drift.

Comment: I've read this a couple of times and am still not clear on what the rule is that you're trying to apply. You mention "file number", but haven't defined what that means. It would be helpful if you included a list of each different type of file name, what the input is, and what the expected output would be. For example, you said some files don't contain an underscore in the name, yet you have no examples of those, and have not described if any of them should be returned from the query.

Comment: If all your files begin with `IM00441` or what ever your number is: `IM + num`, what is the issue? It seems to me anything can be after these?

Comment: FYI, you don't need to convert to `ToUpperInvariant` to do a case-insensitive comparison. `StartsWith` has an overload that you can use: `StartsWith(LocalFile, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`

Comment: Can you not just use `Contains` against the string you need to match?

Comment: @David Wright - The characters before are always alpha, but after can be alpha, numeric, or a combination

Comment: @Simon Wilson - di.GetFiles($"*{FileNumber}*.jpg") will still get the imagefiles named IM00441*.jpg AND IM00441A*.jpg. I just need (for this example all the image files named IM00441*.jpg, but none of the image files named IM00441A*.jpg

Comment: @TVOHM - I have tried that and it doesn’t matter if I use StartsWith or Contains - any image file name that starts with IM00441 also starts with IM00441A and the same with contains - both contain IM00441

Comment: @Rufus L - Thanks, I didn’t know about that

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [Regular Expressions](https://regexone.com/references/csharp) for this.

Here's an example (substitute the `00441` in the `pattern` variable for the file name you are searching for):

```cs
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

// ...

var files = new List<string>
{
    "IM00441_000A.jpg", 
    "IM00441_205A.jpg", 
    "IM00441_110D.jpg", 
    "IM00441_A11.jpg",  
    "IM00441A_000A.JPG",
    "IM00441A_105A.JPG",
    "IM00441A_110A.JPG",
    "IM00441A_302A.JPG",
    "IM00123_123A.jpg", 
    "IM00123A_123B.jpg",
    "AIM00123_123C.jpg",
    "IM00456_123A.jpg", 
    "IM00456A_123B.jpg",
    "AIM00456_123C.jpg" 
};

var pattern = @".+00441.*\.[jpg|JPG]";

foreach (var file in files)
{
    if (Regex.IsMatch(file, pattern))
        Console.WriteLine($"Found file: {file}");
}       

// Output:
//     Found file: IM00441_000A.jpg
//     Found file: IM00441_205A.jpg
//     Found file: IM00441_110D.jpg
//     Found file: IM00441_A11.jpg
//     Found file: IM00441A_000A.JPG
//     Found file: IM00441A_105A.JPG
//     Found file: IM00441A_110A.JPG
//     Found file: IM00441A_302A.JPG
```